Why QOpenGLWidget.devicePixelRatio() isn't one?
I upgraded from pyqt4 to pyside6. I've just wasted hours trying to figure out why  the mouse pick algorithm wasn't working until I found out that the devicePixelRatio is 1.5. Why isn't it 1? How do I set it to 1?
It's a PySide6QtOpenGLWidgets.QOpenGLWidget (inside a window), and a c++ extension responds to its events (painting, mouse..).

To clarify,

I'm asking about a scenario when this would be useful. The scenario needs to be more common than reading the mouse position at mouse events wrongly (need to account for the scale)--to make it the default behavior.
I'm not asking about changing the ratio in my OS but in the app like it used to. Something in the lines of QOpenGLPaintDevice().setDevicePixelRatio().


You should support any scale. Even if you disable this scaling in your OS settings somehow, your users might have non-1 scaling too.

This issue possibly arose when Qt5 introduced (additional) support for high DPI displays, that the upgrade from Qt4 to Qt6 didn't account for. Why it isn't 1, is a question for the display manufacturer. As HolyBlackCat says, it's better to take it into account than to ignore it.
